# How often should i give bath to my cat? She feels so much afraid of water

Tags: cats, bathing

My cat feels so scared of bath. And whenever i give her bath she tries to attack me and acts so aggressive. So i want to know how often should i give her bath and what should i do to make her feel less scare of water.

Comment: do you need to give your cat a bath at all,please update your question and tell why you think your cat needs a bath.

Answer (score 4):

Cats are well-known for having a natural dislike of water (with some exceptions); they don't like to be wet and aren't going to stay in a situation where they're getting wet, so it should come as no surprise that your cat is attempting to escape when you submerge her in water.

The nice thing about cats is that **it's generally unnecessary to bathe them** at all. Unlike dogs, cats are self-cleaning creatures who don't require regular baths outside of certain exceptions:

> - Your cat has been skunked, soiled himself, or rolled in some indescribable source of nasty;
> - Your cat is a hairless breed, in which case(because of their unnatural physiology and production of excess oils) they’ll need to
>     have a bath once a week;
> - Your cat is a recent rescue from the street and is exceedingly filthy and/or covered with fleas;
> - Your cat is either elderly and doesn't groom much anymore, or is obese and can’t effectively clean themselves.(In either case, they can be wiped down with a baby wipe.)

(source: https://www.jacksongalaxy.com/blog/how-often-should-i-bathe-my-cat/)

Some people may also choose to bathe their cats to control allergies or because they have some other issue preventing them from grooming themselves, but for the most part, you do not need to give your cat baths. Instead of thinking about how to change something that's fundamentally part of how cats think, ask yourself why you're bathing your cat so often. And if you don't have a very strong reason like the ones above, I would suggest you stop putting her through the stressful experience of bathing and just allow her to take care of cleaning herself.

Comment: this answer is the only answer to this question,i have had cats for a long long time and i have given my cats a bath less than once per decade on average.

Comment: +1 I've never had to give my cats a bath.. you can tell by how my internal organs have remained mostly internal and I still have sufficient fingers left to type this.